# json_decode help

Tags: php, json, api, vimeo

I have been trying to use some API's from various services, At the moment im trying to retrieve data about a video on vimeo,

I have successfully got the file and read the contents, however, i do not know how to access each part of the file that is returned as a .json.

Basically, how do i access the data in the json file using PHP

Thanks

Comment: To help with json_decode I use this online formatter, which makes it easier to read the structure: http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/group/awesome/videos.json"), true);
```

Read it into a variable using:

```
$data = json_decode($file_contents);
```

then you can access the parts using:

```
echo $data->id;
echo $data->title;
```

etc.

Just use `print_r($data);` to see all available fields.

Comment: $xmldata = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/22099921.json';

$open = fopen($xmldata,'r');

$content = stream_get_contents($open);


 $data = json_decode($content);
echo $data ->thumbnail_medium;

is my full code, its just a test page, I get errror Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: instead of echo $data->thumbnail_medium, use: foreach($data as $val)
{
    echo $val->thumbnail_medium;
}

Comment: Managed to solve it, I was using $data -> thumbnail_medium, but i didn't specifuy the elemnt number so i now have $data[0] -> thumbnail_medium and that works.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function?

Comment: Asking a question of the asker is most appropriately done via comment under the question.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is just [*JSON*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json), you can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("url here"), true);
```

and then access the data like a normal [**array**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Of course you have to know the structure of the data you get in order to access it correctly. You can always use loops to iterate over it as well.

If the data is delivered as [*JSONP*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), you have to process it before, to remove the padding. [I created a function for that](https://github.com/fkling/PHP-functions/raw/master/jsonp_util.php).

**Update:**

In one of the comments you posted a link to the JSON file:

```
$data->video
```

does not work because

1. `$data` is an array. `$data[0]->something` will work
2. `video` does not exist as property of the object.

Do a `print_r($data)` to see the structure.

Comment: The code i have been using is 


 $json_decoded = json_decode($content);
echo $json_decoded->video;

with the $content variable being the JSON file... when i run this page i get "Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: @nmyster: Then you should check what `$content` really contains. It could be that it is JSONP or JSON with wrong syntax. `json_last_error` will help you a bit to find out what went wrong: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Managed to solve it, I was using $data -> thumbnail_medium, but i didn't specifuy the elemnt number so i now have $data[0] -> thumbnail_medium and that works.